# A script that creates a note in cell "D1" of values found in a range "A1:C4"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Example]

Is it possible to create a script so that when I change any value in the range A1:C4 it also changes the notes in "D1"? (See Example above)

Comment: Possible`````````````````​````````````````` See [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var editRange='A1:C4',
    cellOut='D1',
    SheetName='SetNote';

var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var rowEdit = e.range.getRow(),
    colEdit = e.range.getColumn(),
    firstRowRange = ss.getRange(editRange).getRow(),
    firstColRange =ss.getRange(editRange).getColumn(),
    lastRowRange = ss.getRange(editRange).getLastRow(),
    lastColRange = ss.getRange(editRange).getLastColumn();
if (((rowEdit-firstRowRange)*(rowEdit-lastRowRange)<=0)&&((colEdit-firstColRange)*(colEdit-lastColRange)<=0)&&(ss.getName()==SheetName))
    {var value=ss.getRange(editRange).getValues(),
         note='';
     for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) {for(var j=0;j<value[i].length;j++) 
                                          {note+=value[i][j];
                                           if(j<value[i].length-1) note+='\t';}
                                      if(i<value.length-1) note+='\n';}                 
     ss.getRange(cellOut).setNote(note);}
}
```